# How to make domain change on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, web, mobile

My question is, **how can I make it so that when someone enters a domain via the mobile phone they are directed to another domain**.
As for example with Twitter, if we are in the browser on the phone and put *https://twitter.com* it will automatically direct to *https://mobile.twitter.com*

Comment: What have you tried? What software or service are you using to host? Do you want to do this via javascript or in that software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in vanilla JS just do a condition check after the DOM load event.

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|Mac|Macintosh|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    window.location.replace('mobileurl');
    /// or window.location.href = 'mobileurl';
}
```